# Maintain data integrity between MySQL and Files System

Tags: mysql, file, sqlalchemy

Basically, I am storing some files that are linked with a row in MySQL database

Since there is cascading in my database so if I removed the parent record, the childeren records will be deleted including these rows that are linked to the files stored in the File System

How can I make sure if I deleted the record row from the database the file linked with that row is also removed from the files system to maintain data integrity? Any automated ways. I am using SQLAlchemy in Flask.

I know I can do that manually for I am looking for automated methods like cascading in database.

Comment: "I am looking for automated methods like cascading in database." Not possible MySQL can't delete files imagine if it would be possible if there was a SQL injection..

Comment: How about listeners, aboutnin SQLAlchemy? Can they do the job. Do u have any experiance with that?

Comment: "How can I make sure if I deleted the record row from the database the file linked with that row is also removed from the files system to maintain data integrity? " ... But you can start a MySQL transaction to delete the record and check in SQLAlchemy if the transaction did work without a error then delete the file also.. Thats a pretty safe way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in to standard MySQL or MariaDB to do this. And, triggers won't fire when rows are deleted by cascading constraints.

I've had to do this kind of thing in the past. I have had good success with a two-stage delete process. In the first stage, a column called `active` in the master table is set to zero, marking it out of service.

In the second stage, performed in batches maybe overnight, a cleanup program locates `active = 0` rows, finds the files mentioned in the master file rows and the related rows, deletes the files, then deletes the rows.

There's nothing automatic about it, but it works.